# Difference between webview and iframe and use cases on flutter

Tags: flutter, iframe, webview

I would like to know the difference between webview and iframe along with their corresponding use cases in flutter.

From my understanding, iframe is used mostly on flutter web in order to embed some other source code, and is only available to a flutter android or ios app via a webview which has an iframe as a child. Is this correct? If this is the case, why not use only webview to display the content I want both on flutter web and on android,ios and avoid code complication? Is webview not available on flutter web? When should I use one or the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`WebView` widget is often used to include an `iframe` when you want to utilise it in a Flutter mobile app.

**`iframe`**

- Using the `iframe` HTML element, you may include content from another website or webpage into your own.
- It may be used to integrate third-party widgets or tools or to show material from another website or business.
- However, because the material inside the iframe is separate from the rest of your website, there are limits to its personalization and interactivity.
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html

**`Webview`**

- Can show online information inside of your mobile app using WebView, a native component.
- As you can interact with the site content using native code and have greater control over how it is displayed and organised, it is more powerful and adaptable than an iframe.
  *But if not used, it can have security and performance problems and is more difficult to set up.*
- https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

**Use Cases:**

- `iframe` is a suitable option if all you need to do is embed external material into a webpage (like a YouTube video or a Twitter feed) without having to interact with it or modify it in any way.
- `WebView` is a preferable choice if you want greater control over how the material is shown and interacted with, or if you're developing a mobile app that must show online content.

***Note:*** unlike `iframe`, which is exclusively available on the web platform, `WebView` is supported by both the Flutter mobile and web platforms. Therefore, you must utilise `WebView` if you want to show external information on both the web and mobile devices.

Comment: can't I also show an iframe in mobile through a WebView?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter doesn't support web